# Script tags are being nested even though I'm closing one before opening the next one

Tags: html, jsp, tags, nested, script-tag

I'm trying to export two external scripts into a JSP and to declare one on the JSP body itself. Altogether, I have three  tags on my code. They look like his:

```
<script src="dist/jstree.min.js" />
<script src="dist/libs/jquery.js" />
<script>
     $(function () {
     (...)
</script>
```

For some reason, however, when I open the JSP on my browser, it renders things like this:

```
<script src="dist/jstree.min.js">

    <script src="dist/libs/jquery.js"/><script>
      $(fu…

</script>
```

That is, it's skipping the end of the first script and interpreting everything else as a String. I've tried explicitly writing `</script>` as opposed to /> but it behaves the same way. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I started the file from scratch but instead of making it a .jsp, I created a plain .html and it worked. Still no idea why multiple script tags were being automatically nested on the JSP and not on the HTML

Answer (score 1):

> Every browser that supports XHTML (Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE9)
>   supports self-closing syntax on every element.

Having this on hand, if you dont have a valid XHTML document, you might end up having problems with self-closing tags, most commonly if the given tag is empty (as in your script tags that load the script from the src), I recommend doing as follows in order to avoid issues:

```
<script src="dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function () {
     (...)
</script>
```

Comment: I tried both, but neither worked. Every time I inspected the html on the browser, it showed the first scritp tag interpreting the other ones as Strings. If the first script tag was the internal one (that is, without the src attribute), that one was isolated from the others, but the two external scripts were nested regardless. This was solved when I copied the whole thing from the .jsp to a plain .html file. Reason still unknown.